# What does "reduced advertising" mean?

Tags: support, reputation, advertising

What does "reduced advertising" mean? I mean, what are you awarded when you reach 200 rep? (I just got past it, woo-hoo!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below 200 rep, there is an ad banner at the top of each question page, as well as along the right side.

Above 200 rep, only the ads on the right side appear.

Here's an example:

[image: image of examples of advertising]

Comment: Aww, imgur fail. :(

Answer (score 4):

The ad bar near the top of the page (just below the question title) is removed. I believe there are ads that appear in the Answers section that are also removed. Although there are still ads on the sidebar, it makes questions and answers easier to read not having any ads mingled in. That's your gift for getting 200 Rep!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is fully implemented on SU right now as I'm under 200 there, but am not seeing the adds differently. But on SF I know that there are adds above the question and below the first answer that I don't see on the other sites. I believe these are the ones removed when you reach 200.

Comment: Even when not logged in to SuperUser, I haven't seen any ads below the title, just on the sidebar.

Comment: I think perhaps because SU is still beta, that this may not be turned on.

Comment: gnovice, are you running any software that blocks ads? Adblock extension for Firefox?

Comment: @T Pops: Not that I know of. If I open any of the other sites without logging in I still see the extra ads. It's just SU where they are gone.